# How to cast a string to an Enum during instantiation of a dataclass in Python

Tags: python, enums, casting, callable, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass `DummyClass` with an attribute `dummy` that can only take two values: `"foo"` and `"bar"`. I would like to use an `Enum` class for this attribute so that an error is raised when using an invalid value:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import Enum

class DummyAttribute(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"

@dataclass
class DummyClass:
    dummy: DummyAttribute
```

The problem is that I would like to instantiate `DummyClass` using a string (not using the `DummyAttribute` class directly). One way to do it would be using the `__post_init__` method:

```
@dataclass
class DummyClass:
    dummy: DummyAttribute = field(init=False)
    tmp_dummy: str
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.dummy = DummyAttribute(self.tmp_dummy)
```

However I would prefer to avoid adding a `tmp_dummy` attribute and a `__post_init__` method. Is there any more concise way of casting the input string to the `DummyAttribute` enum?

---

**Edit:**
@chepner answer helped me find an even more concise way of doing it:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import Enum

class DummyAttribute(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"

@dataclass
class DummyClass:
    dummy: str | DummyAttribute
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.dummy = DummyAttribute(self.dummy)
```

Please let me know if there is a better way!

Comment: Why not use `DummyAttribute`? `foobar = DummyClass(DummyAttribute("foo"))`. (`DummyClass("foo")` would be a type error caught by `mypy`.)

Comment: Because the value of the attribute actually comes from a big file where only some values need to be Enum. Thus casting some of this values to Enum before instantiating the class would require changing a lot of code.

Comment: So you already have `DummyClass("foo")` being called, but you want to change the type of the existing attribute from `str` to `DummyAttribute`?

Comment: Exactly. Regarding your first comment, I edited the question adding one possible solution that would not throw a mypy error.

Comment: Ha! That's what I just recommended :)

Comment: One difference: using `InitVar` for `tmp_dummy` prevents the creation of an attribute; it *only* gets passed to `__post_init__`.

Comment: Didn't know about `InitVar`! This solves one of the problems, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `__post_init__` (as you edited added to your question) is your best alternative. `dataclass` doesn't support the kind of value transformer you want. (For that, you might want to look at Pydantic or the `attrs` package.)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar
from enum import Enum

class DummyAttribute(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"


@dataclass
class DummyClass:
    dummy: DummyAttribute = field(init=False)
    dummyStr: InitVar[str]

    def __post_init__(self, dummyStr):
        self.dummy = DummyAttribute(dummyStr)
```

Comment: The only problem with your answer was that the name of the input kwarg is changed to `dummyStr`, and I would prefer not to change it. However I found a solution to this problem (I added it after my question). Let me know what you think! :)

Comment: That could have consequences if you are actually using something like `mypy`. You're saying that it's ok for `dummy` to be a string or a `DummyAttribute`, even if you initialize it to be a `DummyAttribute`.

Comment: But the names are easily changed; use whatever fits your code. I assumed the name `DummyAttribute` isn't actually used in the production code :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using an `Enum`, if what you really need is a `str` type then I would suggest just using a `str` instead.

Note that `typing.Literal` might be helpful in this case:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Literal


@dataclass
class DummyClass:
    dummy: Literal['foo', 'bar']

    def __post_init__(self):
        # TODO: assert that `self.dummy` is one of valid Literal values
        ...
```

Then you can create your instances like this, and right off the bat your IDE should throw warnings at you if you pass an invalid `Literal` value for a field.

```
obj1 = DummyClass('bar')
obj2 = DummyClass('blah')  # <-- warning! >:(
```

As mentioned, if you actually need to *validate* that it's one of the valid `Literal` values, I would suggest adding that logic to the `__post_init__` method.